# uicollectionview's dynamic height as per row values

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, sizetofit

hello friends i am using collection view in iPhone application to show list.
I want to set the height of the collection view as per size of my list.
how can I set it?

also have the problem when I use set selected method of cell in the collection view it will disable the user interaction.

I don't know what is the reason?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried in viewDidLayoutSubview method or in viewDidAppear.. giving this height dynamicHeight  =  collectionView.contentSize.height

Comment: but it will give height to my cells not to the collection view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"set selected method of cell in the collection view it will disable the user interaction."

this is solved by adding following method.

```
[newCell setSelected:YES]; 

[collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

accordingly.

as per given in this link

[UICollectionView Select and Deselect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330844/uicollectionview-select-and-deselect-issue)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,after completion of your collection view you can get content size based on that value you can change frame of  collection.

```
dynamicHeight  =  collectionView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: thank you for your reply sunny. But this will set the cell height as per return value. 
i want to set height of whole collection view.

Comment: in that case you can take one global varaible and add heights of each cell to that varaible and then keep it as height of that Collectionview

Comment: but where i have to set this dynamic height to my collection view? i mean in which method should i place it?

Comment: and i also use UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

In `heightforrowatindexpath` try doing this

```
return [array count]*(your cell's content height);
```

Comment: this method is not with collection view this method works for tableview.

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView have a different realization other than UITableView, and i recommend to use [RZCellSizeManager](https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZCellSizeManager)
Or just learn how it works.

Comment: this is cell size and this is tableview i want to use dynamic height in uicollectionview.

Comment: No. it's support both. This library work like cache of cell.

_RZCellSizeManager is an object used to streamline the calculation, caching, and retrieval of sizes for UICollectionView cells and heights for UITableView cells. It pairs particularly nicely with AutoLayout but can be used anytime you want to simplify management of cell sizes._