# UICollectionView cell user interaction disabled

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

I am using collection view in iPhone application to show list.
now while using the cell for row at the index path method I am using set selected to yes.
this will make my cell user interaction disable.
I don't know what is the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it by adding method.

```
    [newCell setSelected:YES];  



[collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
```

accordingly.

as per given in this link  [UICollectionView Select and Deselect issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330844/uicollectionview-select-and-deselect-issue)

Thanks.